# How do I install opencv-python 4.1.1.26 on NVIDIA Jetson AGX Xavier?

Tags: python, opencv, nvidia-jetson

I have tried installing it using pip3 but it seems like there is no available version for aarch64 architecture, are there any other ways I can install it?

Also if I were to clone the code here, https://github.com/skvark/opencv-python/releases/tag/26
and compile it, may I know what are the steps for it? (Sorry for asking, I'm still fairly new to these stuff) Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

Could you share the error you get while trying to install it?

you can also try the below:

```
pip3 install scikit-build
pip3 install opencv-python==4.1.1.26
```

Regards,